# How to get runtime classpath in gradle kts script?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In gradle script I can do `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` to get the runtime classpath. But in kts script it complains

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public val NamedDomainObjectContainer<Configuration>.runtimeClasspath: NamedDomainObjectProvider<Configuration> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

How can I do it in kts script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that I need `sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath` . Not sure if it is the most idiomatic way